# function definition does not declare parameters simple c++ programme

Tags: c++, class, debugging

This is my class `employeeException`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class employeeException
{
    public:
    employeeException(string);
    void printmessage();

    private:
    string message;
};

int main()
{  
  employeeException("Heelo");
}

employeeException::employeeException(string message)
{
    this->message = message;
}

void employeeException:printmessage()
{
    cout<<endl
        <<this->message
        <<endl;
}
```

For some unknown reason , I get this error during compilation

> function definition does not declare parameters

I can't figure out what is wrong with this simple program. Surely, I am missing something simple.

Comment: Double colon in front of printmessage(), not worth an answer.

Comment: *"I cant figure out what is wrong"*  Why not?? Did you actually carefully read the line of code referred to by the error message, *character-by-character*??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void employeeException:printmessage()
                      ^ - missing a colon
{
    cout<<endl
        <<this->message
        <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `::` on this function:

```
employeeException::employeeException(string message)
```

***but not on this one? (where you only have one `:`):***

```
void employeeException:printmessage()
```